# Django web project not running

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

1. My Web Application is not running on the new system it says it does not recognize "python"/ "pip as an internal and external command.
2. My Powershell Terminal

   ```
    '''
      PS C:\Users\Nawaf  Bhatti\Desktop\learn> python -m pip install pillow
      python: The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
      file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
      of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
      At line:1 char:1
      + python -m pip install pillow
        + ~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
     '''
   ```
3. My cmd

   ```
      '''
      C:\Users\Nawaf  Bhatti\Desktop\learn\web_app>python manage.py runserver
       'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     operable program or batch file.
     '''
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your computer doesn't pick up the python installation,

Try running the command

```
python --version
```

It should reply with the python version installed:

```
Python 3.9.9
```

If an error occur, try running the following in cmd:

```
python3 --version
```

If the version then appears, it means you have to run your code with:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Alternatively go to the Microsoft store and install python there and then run the above commands, if your version then appear then you can return to your normal way of running server

Here is a link for [python](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/python-39/9p7qfqmjrfp7#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) on your Microsoft store

Comment: still not recognizing

Comment: How to activate virtualenv in the existing project ?